# fabric8 -The last operation resulted in the following error: Unauthorized

Tags: fabric8

I am working with kubernetes on google cloud,
I have created a fabric8 cluster: http://fabric8.io/guide/getStarted/gke.html

when the cluster is up and running i pull remote repositories and it works but when i try create a new app and i get the following msg:

The last operation resulted in the following error:

> Unauthorized
>
> log:2016-08-21T16:39:07.505206481Z Both
>   io.fabric8.forge.rest.git.RepositoriesResource#projectRepositoryResource
>   and
>   io.fabric8.forge.rest.git.RepositoriesResource#projectRepositoryResource
>   are equal candidates for handling the current request which can lead
>   to unpredictable results

can any body help me understand what this error means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any chance of seeing the full log of the fabric8-forge pod?

> kubectl logs fabric8-forge-xxxx

Were you creating a project using the wizard using the gogs git server or did you try to import a project from an external git repository?

Comment: Both io.fabric8.forge.rest.CommandsResource#validateCommand and io.fabric8.forge.rest.CommandsResource#validateCommand are equal candidates for handling the current request which can lead to unpredictable results
Stashing local changes to the repo
Performing a pull in git repository /tmp/fabric8-forge/jenkinsWorkflows/.git on remote URL: https://github.com/fabric8io/jenkins-workflow-library.git
Using UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider{user: gogsadmin, password length: 0}
Outbound Message

Comment: That looks the the password you added to your secret is of zero length. This could be a bug in the Secret UI, the browser can autodefault the password field but sometimes angularjs hasn't seen the value yet. Try explicitly type the password in the Secret UI then try aga?

Comment: ok,i think i know what the issue was,when accessing the kubernetes cluster from google i run kubectl proxy and use http://localhost:8001/ui and it didnt prompt me for user password,when i access fabric8 with localhost it also dosent prompt for user password,when i changed the the cluster ip i could finally create project :), thank James for the quick answer :)|