# fabric8 -how to deploy deploy with gitk keys and create new projects in google cloud

Tags: fabric8

I am working in google cloud with kubernetes and deployed the cluster like in the examples
i downloaded gofabric8-0.4.42-darwin-amd64.tar.gz and deploy it and i am running into a few issues:

1. i cant create new projects -> The last operation resulted in the following error: Unauthorized with no errors in the log
   link to question :
   [fabric8 -The last operation resulted in the following error: Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066599/fabric8-the-last-operation-resulted-in-the-following-error-unauthorized)
2. how can i deploy fabric8 with ssh key to my git ?

note:i am working with gitlab

LOGS:

Error occurred during error handling, give up!
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Failed to command remote repo git@:backend/bash-parser.git due: ssh://git@:22: org.eclipse.jgit.transport.CredentialItem$YesNoType:The authenticity of host '' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 46:24:24:04:ca:83:62:33:0c:c0:85:4e:21:ea:4d:fa.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting?
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162)[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:128)[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:189)[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:99)[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:254)[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180)[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:298)[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:217)[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)[servlet-api-3.1.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:273)[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:837)[jetty-servlet-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)[jetty-servlet-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)[jetty-server-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)[jetty-security-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)[jetty-server-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)[jetty-server-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)[jetty-servlet-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)[jetty-server-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)[jetty-server-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)[jetty-server-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)[jetty-server-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)[jetty-server-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)[jetty-server-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:524)[jetty-server-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:319)[jetty-server-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:253)[jetty-server-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)[jetty-io-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)[jetty-io-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)[jetty-io-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)[jetty-util-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)[jetty-util-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)[jetty-util-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)[jetty-util-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)[jetty-util-9.3.10.v20160621.jar:9.3.10.v20160621]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_91]

Answer (score 0):

1. See the [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066599/fabric8-the-last-operation-resulted-in-the-following-error-unauthorized) for where we can answer that one
2. To import a project from your own git repository you will need to create a Secret in your users namespace (e.g. in the *user-secrets-source-admin* namespace) to contain your SSH key, user/password or github user and token.

Then when you import the project (via Team -> Team Dashboard -> Create Application -> Import from Git) after you've supplied the git URL you can select the Secret you wish to use with your git repository so that the git repository can be cloned & edited.

Its a little easier to use HTTPS URLS with git repository as you can then just use user/passwords - or better - use user name + tokens from (say) github. But if you use a ssh based URL for a git repo then you'll have to import your public + private keys into the Secret.

Comment: Hi James and thanks for the quick reply, beacuse i create the fabric8 cluster according to the doc in https://fabric8.io/guide/getStarted/gke.html , i created a secret ssh key like this :  kubectl --namespace="user-secrets-source-admin" create secret generic my-secret --from-file=ssh-privatekey=/Users/Amit/.ssh/id_rsa --from-file=ssh-publickey=/Users/Amit/.ssh/id_rsa.pub . then when i click on improt project and reach the point were i need to choose a secret,the i have no secret to choose from , any ideas?